# How to use pop and push in one query with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to do this two "operation" in one query

```
const deleteUser = await BOQ.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, { $pop: { user: 1 }});
const assignUser = await BOQ.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {$push:{user: req.params.userId}})
```

If it possible can anyone tell me how ?

I try

```
    const deleteUser = await BOQ.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, { $pop: { user: 1 }},
    {$push: {user: req.params.userId}});
```

But it won`t work

Answer (score 1):

```
const deleteUser = await BOQ.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    {
        $pop: { user: 1 },
        $push: { user: req.params.userId }
    }
);
```

The second paramter is a document of update operators. You can refer the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) for more detail on the parameters.

Comment: I get error "Updating the path 'user' would create a conflict at 'user' "

Comment: are you using same value for push and pop?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `$push` and `$pop` operators together in the same query.

What you can do, however, is use the `$push` operator with [`$slice`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#modifiers) modifier. This will ensure that only a fixed number of items are held within the array -- and will effectively "pop" items off the start or end depending on the value of `$slice`.

For example, the following ensures that only two items are kept in the array. New ones go to the end, and old ones are removed from the start. `arr` is the field name which has to be an array for this to work.

```
{
    $push: {
        arr: {
            $each: [ "new_item_value" ],
            $slice: -2,
    },
}
```

This may not work in your use case, but this seems to be the only way to do both push and pop in a single call.